# Unable to find System preference options

Tags: 14.04

I have recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 but I am unable to find system preference options. Where are these options and how can I find them?

Answer (score 2):

Are you following a guide from years ago?  I believe you may be looking for Additional Drivers.  You can find this by running "software & updates", then going to the "Additional Drivers" tab.  Or you can try searching for "Additional Drivers" directly from the launcher.

Comment: yes u r right.i got it